# Cascading list help

Tags: list, cascading

I am trying to create a cascading list without using a jQuery. My company has disabled my ability to edit the master page so I need to have the ability to use a different function

Comment: You don’t need to edit the master page to do that. You can put it right on the New and Edit forms.

Comment: you can add content edit web part on the page and paste your javascript there.

Answer (score 0):

To create a cascading list, no need to have permission on the master page.
You can add script editor to Add and Edit form.
In that script editor, add Javascript code like fallows,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>  
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">           
$(document).ready(function ()  
{  
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
{  
    relationshipList: "Employee",  
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Team",  
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",  
    parentColumn: "Team",  
    childColumn: "Employee",  
    debug: true  
});  
}); 
</script>
```

To know clearly refer the [Cascading of Lookup Drop Down Fields on SharePoint 2013 and Office 365](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/), Hope it will help you to know more.